# Windows 10 LTSB v. 1607 & Spectre: Still no OS support for mitigation

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, spectre

I've got a Dell XPS 15 9560 running Windows 10 LTSB 2016 (build 1607). The CPU is an Intel i7 7700HQ. For nearly a month now, I've been trying to ensure that this machine is protected against the recently discovered Spectre vulnerability (CVE-2017-5715), without success. I'm aware that microcode/bios updates are required to fully implement the mitigation for this vulnerability, but that isn't my concern today. My problem is that the Windows updates that are supposed to address this CVE apparently do not.

Microsoft has released 2 patches so far related to this issue - the first, [KB4056890](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056890/windows-10-update-kb4056890), was released in early January. Another, [KB4057142](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057142/windows-10-update-kb4057142), has now superseded that patch. I've also installed the latest BIOS for this machine, but that is beside the point.

In either case, running the new SpeculationControl cmdlet for powershell shows something rather concerning:

```
Hardware support for branch target injection mitigation is present: False
Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is present: False
Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is enabled: False

Speculation control settings for CVE-2017-5754 [rogue data cache load]

Hardware requires kernel VA shadowing: True
Windows OS support for kernel VA shadow is present: True
Windows OS support for kernel VA shadow is enabled: True
Windows OS support for PCID performance optimization is enabled: True [not required for security]

BTIHardwarePresent             : False
BTIWindowsSupportPresent       : False
BTIWindowsSupportEnabled       : False
BTIDisabledBySystemPolicy      : False
BTIDisabledByNoHardwareSupport : False
KVAShadowRequired              : True
KVAShadowWindowsSupportPresent : True
KVAShadowWindowsSupportEnabled : True
KVAShadowPcidEnabled           : True
```

Emphasis on these 2 lines:

**Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is present: False**

**BTIWindowsSupportPresent       : False**

Powershell's Get-Hotfix cmdlet verifies that the latest version of the spectre/meltdown patches is present:

```
<12:37:48 2 C:\> Get-HotFix

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
...
BLAH-PC       Update           KB4057142     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  1/26/2018 00:00:00
...
```

My understanding is that regardless of the state of the CPU microcode, these lines should read 'true' once the OS patch has been applied. I've also tried setting and unsetting the registry keys mentioned [in this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4072698/windows-server-guidance-to-protect-against-the-speculative-execution) under the heading "Disable mitigation against Spectre Variant 2 independently", to no effect at all.

Why is this fully patched and updated copy of Windows 10 still not able to support mitigation of CVE-2017-5715? What can I do to enable support for these mitigations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware that microcode/bios updates are required to fully implement
>   the mitigation for this vulnerability, but that isn't my concern
>   today. My problem is that the Windows updates that are supposed to
>   address this CVE apparently do not.

It really should not be a concern.  The microcode which has been pulled by Intel is required to mitigate the Spectre variant 2, without it being installed on your system the patches released by Microsoft cannot be used.

> Our own experience is that system instability can in some
>   circumstances cause data loss or corruption. On January 22nd Intel
>   recommended that customers stop deploying the current microcode
>   version on impacted processors while they perform additional testing
>   on the updated solution. We understand that Intel is continuing to
>   investigate the potential impact of the current microcode version and
>   encourage customers to review their guidance on an ongoing basis to
>   inform their decisions."

At this point, you really don't want the fixes Intel wrote, if you installed the current fix you would regret it.  [Microsoft issues emergency weekend update to remove buggy Intel patch](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-pushes-emergency-weekend-update-to-remove-buggy-intel-patch)

> In either case, running the new SpeculationControl cmdlet for
>   PowerShell shows something rather concerning.

It shouldn't be concerning.  It's what you should expect out of a system that has not received the required microcode to implement the mitigation steps done within the kernel that uses a particular instruction.

> My understanding is that regardless of the state of the CPU microcode,
>   these lines should read 'true' once the OS patch has been applied.  Why is this fully patched and updated copy of Windows 10 still not able to support mitigation of CVE-2017-5715?

You are mistaken.  2017-5715 requires a microcode.  Without the microcode, the kernel changes done by the update(s) in question, cannot be used and are ignored.

[image]

> What can I do to enable support for these mitigations?

Install the updated firmware, when it's released, but be sure you only do it after Intel releases the updated fixes.

> I've also tried setting and unsetting the registry keys mentioned in
>   this article under the heading "Disable mitigation against Spectre
>   Variant 2 independently", to no effect at all.

This key is ignored, if you have not patched your firmware, so the required firmware can be used.  It also would be used if you had an AMD system which you do not.

> Why is this fully patched and updated copy of Windows 10 still not
>   able to support mitigation of CVE-2017-5715?

Intel pulled the required microcode and Microsoft released an optional patch that disables the current unstable microcode code. Variant 2 CANNOT BE mitigated with kernel changes itself. Spectre variant 2 requires a firmware updated by Dell in order to receive the microcode. Intel has not released the fixed/corrected microcode at this time.